# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: "to" argument must be of type string in Next.js project

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

I'm developing a Next.js application and encountered a `TypeError` related to the "to" argument being undefined. This error occurs when I run my development server with `npm run dev`. I've checked my environment setup and the related project dependencies but haven't been able to pinpoint the cause of this error.

**Error Message:**
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "to" argument must be of type string. Received undefined
at validateString (node:internal/validators:162:11)
at Object.relative (node:path:1195:5)
at Watchpack. (/Users/gracemitchell/com.primebid.estimate/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-utils/setup-dev-bundler.js:1420:55)
...
**Environment:**

- Node.js version: (specify your version, e.g., 20.11.0)
- Next.js version: 14.1.0
- Operating System: (e.g., macOS, specify if relevant)

I've attempted the following troubleshooting steps without success:

1. Checked `.env.local` and other environment configuration files for any obvious issues.
2. Ensured all dependencies are up to date with `npm update`.
3. Searched for similar issues in the Next.js GitHub issues and Stack Overflow.

**Questions:**

1. What could be causing this `TypeError` related to the "to" argument being undefined?
2. Are there specific configurations or dependencies in Next.js that I should check?
3. Has anyone experienced a similar issue and found a workaround or solution?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

1. What could be causing this `TypeError` related to the "to" argument being undefined?
2. Are there specific configurations or dependencies in Next.js that I should check?
3. Has anyone experienced a similar issue and found a workaround or solution?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: check if this was introduced after recent changes and try to isolate the issue by removing those recent changes, if the error goes away try pasting the causing code here if you need further help

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem and in my case it was very simple. I had created a new version of a page using Typescript, but had not deleted the previous Javascript version. So I had in the pages folder

```
/pages/onboarding.js
/pages/onboarding.tsx
```

which were completely different files. The project was probably assuming the .js file was a compiled version of the .tsx file.

I just deleted the old .js file and everything worked again. ✨

The error message does not help at all, though.

Comment: Wow, this worked for me. Useless error message.